# My drop shadow repaints over itself?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have subclassed an UINavigationController adding a drop shadow on method viewDidApper: from UINavigationController like this:

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Add shadow to Navigation Bar
    CAGradientLayer *newShadow = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    newShadow.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    newShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 4.0f);
    newShadow.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    CGRect shadowPath = CGRectMake(self.navigationBar.layer.bounds.origin.x - 10, self.navigationBar.layer.bounds.size.height - 6, self.navigationBar.layer.bounds.size.width + 20, 5);
    newShadow.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowPath].CGPath;
    newShadow.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [self.navigationBar.layer addSublayer:newShadow];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

And when I use this NavigationController in a ModalViewController, the shadow repaints over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `- viewDidAppear:` method is called every time the view **appears.** You may want to move this code into the `- viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thank you, now don't repaint, but paint the shadow on the incorrect position, like 2 mms up.